keymap new shortcut in edit mode
quite accustomed to editing new keyboard shortcuts, I'm having an issue in the following context: I have to massively digitize segments in a mesh where each new vertex has to be plotted in a specific plane: I draw lines in a camera view which has a dedicated transform orientation, and I need to draw vertice in the XY plane of this orientation. So in edit mode I can do it by typing E then Shift+Z but I would enjoy having a dedicated one-key shortcut for this action. I cannot figure out how to achieve this in the Preferences>Keymap menu. Any help ?
Thanks,
V.
